# On Knaster-Kuratowski fan (aka Cantor's teepee)

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

As definition of Knaster-Kuratowski fan I take the one on wikipedia. Now, part of the definition of this space is the Cantor set. My question is what particular property of Cantor set we necessary need in order to have an example of connected topological space which becomes totally disconnected upon removal of a single point? Can we replace the Cantor set with another uncountable totally disconnected space and still have the example?

Comment: Does the example uses the property of Cantor set that it is nowhere dense?

Comment: It's not immediately clear how you would go about the construction of a generalised Knaster–Kuratowski fan.  The specific construction does one thing to the points of the Cantor set which are endpoints of open intervals removed in the usual iterative construction, and a different this to the remainder of the Cantor set. How would you go about a more general construction?

Comment: I think it is also pretty clear that if you do something "Knaster–Kuratowski fan"-ish to a set of reals with an isolated point, then the resulting space will not be connected (since you could find an open subset of the plan which contains the bottom "half" of the fragment of the line segment joining the isolated point to the apex, but which is far away from the line segments joining the other points of your set to the apex).